# Creating new Credentials object from stored AccessToken and RefreshToken

Tags: java, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-oauth-java-client

I'm following the [Implementing Server Side-Authentication](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/auth/web-server) part of the Google Drive SDK docs, and in the code presented the following part if left as an exercise for the reader:

```
static Credential getStoredCredentials(String userId) {
  // TODO: Implement this method to work with your database. Instantiate a new
  // Credential instance with stored accessToken and refreshToken.
  throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

How does one actually do this, given that we have the `AuthorizationToken` and `RefreshTokens` stored as strings?

Comment: See http://javadoc.google-oauth-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.18.0-rc/com/google/api/client/auth/oauth2/Credential.html